# Best way to convert `Option<Result<_, _>>` into `Result<Option<_>, _>`

Tags: rust

In a larger application I have many functions that return a `Result<_, _>`. Thanks to `?` I can easily compose those. Unfortunately, my code sometimes naturally results in a `Option<Result<_, _>>`. Take this dummy example:

```
std::env::args().nth(1)
    .and_then(|filename| File::open(filename))
```

To easily compose functions that may fail, I want the `Result` at the very "outer level". Of course, `match` helps:

```
match std::env::args().nth(1) {
    Some(filename) => File::open(filename).map(|f| Some(f)),
    None => Ok(None),
}
```

But this is rather verbose and annoying to write. I am searching for a function that helps this conversion. I am somehow reminded of the `FromIterator<Result<A, E>>` impl for `Result<V, E> where V: FromIterator<A>` -- it also pulls the `Result` to the outer layer.

**So what is the best way to achieve what I want?** Writing an own helper function or macro is OK, too.